# Chrome bookmark sync on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, bookmarks

I have two machines with Chrome on them.  One is running Windows 7 and the other is running Ubuntu 9.04.  Both Chrome versions are 4.0.249.43 and both are the beta version.  My Windows 7 PC has bookmark sync enabled but I can't seem to get it enabled on my Ubuntu machine.

The command I use is

> /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
>   --enable-sync

Has anyone had the same problem on Ubuntu 9.04 with Chrome? If fixed, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Chrome 4.0.266.0 and I just had to go to the settings menu -> Options -> Personal Stuff -> Bookmark Sync and set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Raphink you're using a version of chrome that's not the downloadable beta for ubuntu. Probably you're using chromium.